# Foreground application stops receiving keyboard and mouse events from time to time

Tags: window, macos-sierra, window-focus

I've bought new Macbook 12 recently and have this annoying issue when foreground application suddenly stops being foreground. It didn't happen all the time and I cannot reproduce this issue at any time I want.

Foreground application stops receiving keyboard and mouse events. Actually it happened right now as I was typing this text. When I was typing this suddenly text area stop reacting on my keyboard because my browser is not foreground application anymore. I don't have anything that overlap my browser window but I see that it is not foreground application anymore. Even browser header changes its color in the same way as it changes it when you switch application from browser to let's say Finder window.

Comment: Not sure but maybe having "Activity Monitor" open on the side will be helpful, some application may be hijacking your the window on focus?

Comment: unfortunately Activity Monitor does not tell me which process is foreground

Comment: I wonder if you solved the problem. If yes, please share the solution here.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Do you have the same problem?